# Elastic Beanstalk & Django - Requirements.txt Failure

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to setup a Django website on Elastic Beanstalk and am running into some issues relating to my requirements.txt file.  As a result, I'm receiving a status of "degraded" on AWS EB.

When uploading my files, I'm getting the following errors:

```
-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/supervisord.log
-------------------------------------
2016-05-21 13:55:36,633 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-05-21 13:55:36,664 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-05-21 13:55:36,664 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-05-21 13:55:36,665 INFO supervisord started with pid 2034
2016-05-21 13:55:37,675 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 2082
2016-05-21 13:55:39,213 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Sat May 21 14:01:02.579787 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2082] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat May 21 14:01:02.581816 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2082] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat May 21 14:01:02.625308 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2082] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 21 14:01:02.625363 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2082] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/LICENSE.txt  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/METADATA  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/metadata.json  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/RECORD  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/RECORD.jws  
   extracting: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/top_level.txt  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/site-packages/wheel-0.24.0.dist-info/WHEEL  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/sre_compile.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/sre_constants.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/sre_parse.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/stat.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/struct.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/tarfile.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/tempfile.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/token.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/tokenize.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/types.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/warnings.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Lib/weakref.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/activate  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/activate.bat  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/activate.ps1  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/deactivate.bat  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/easy_install.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/easy_install-3.5.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/pip.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/pip3.5.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/pip3.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/python.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/python35.dll  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/pythonw.exe  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/requirements.txt  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/venv/Scripts/wheel.exe  
[2016-05-21T14:20:24.132Z] INFO  [24528] - [Application update 5-21-attempt2@2/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Starting activity...
[2016-05-21T14:20:25.525Z] INFO  [24528] - [Application update 5-21-attempt2@2/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity execution failed, because: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 77, in parse_requirements
      filename, comes_from=comes_from, session=session
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 413, in get_file_content
      content = f.read()
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
      (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2016-05-21 14:20:25,510 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 77, in parse_requirements
      filename, comes_from=comes_from, session=session
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 413, in get_file_content
      content = f.read()
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
      (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2016-05-21 14:20:25,510 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2016-05-21T14:20:25.525Z] INFO  [24528] - [Application update 5-21-attempt2@2/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2016-05-21T14:20:25.525Z] INFO  [24528] - [Application update 5-21-attempt2@2/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2016-05-21T14:20:25.525Z] INFO  [24528] - [Application update 5-21-attempt2@2/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2016-05-21T14:20:25.526Z] INFO  [24528] - [Application update 5-21-attempt2@2] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.880Z] INFO  [24607] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
[2016-05-21T14:20:19.994Z] INFO  [24528] : Loading manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-472212497338' using computed S3 key 'resources/environments/e-72mv7kjmdu/_runtime/versions/manifest_1463840416022'.
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.072Z] INFO  [24528] : Updated manifest cache: deployment ID 2 and serial 2.
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.072Z] DEBUG [24528] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-AppDeploy.
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.073Z] INFO  [24528] : Executing Application update
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] INFO  [24528] : Executing command: CMD-AppDeploy...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] INFO  [24528] : Executing command CMD-AppDeploy activities...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] DEBUG [24528] : Setting environment variables..
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] INFO  [24528] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] DEBUG [24528] : Running stages of Command CMD-AppDeploy from stage 0 to stage 1...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] INFO  [24528] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-AppDeploy...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.074Z] INFO  [24528] : Running leader election...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.491Z] INFO  [24528] : Instance is Leader.
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.491Z] DEBUG [24528] : Loaded 6 actions for stage 0.
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.492Z] INFO  [24528] : Running 1 of 6 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
[2016-05-21T14:20:20.498Z] INFO  [24528] : Running 2 of 6 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
[2016-05-21T14:20:21.382Z] INFO  [24528] : Running 3 of 6 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
[2016-05-21T14:20:21.920Z] INFO  [24528] : Running 4 of 6 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
[2016-05-21T14:20:25.525Z] ERROR [24528] : Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
caused by: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 77, in parse_requirements
      filename, comes_from=comes_from, session=session
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 413, in get_file_content
      content = f.read()
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
      (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2016-05-21 14:20:25,510 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 77, in parse_requirements
      filename, comes_from=comes_from, session=session
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 413, in get_file_content
      content = f.read()
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
      (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2016-05-21 14:20:25,510 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2016-05-21T14:20:25.526Z] ERROR [24528] : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2016-05-21T14:20:25.527Z] INFO  [24528] : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 540, in check_call\n    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)\nCalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.","severity":"ERROR","timestamp":1463840425},{"msg":"Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2","severity":"SYSTEM","timestamp":1463840425}]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.870Z] DEBUG [24607] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.870Z] DEBUG [24607] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] DEBUG [24607] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-07d1992ccb123c519)..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] INFO  [24607] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-07d1992ccb123c519)..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] DEBUG [24607] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] INFO  [24607] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] INFO  [24607] : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAIW4REZPXEJHI5V2Q\",\"signature\":\"TuzNYe0wPSskd\\\/cWzcmWYpMn6AI=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-07d1992ccb123c519"],"data":"34800cef-1f5f-11e6-a5f6-55c78551f5f8","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"34800cef-1f5f-11e6-a5f6-55c78551f5f8","command_timeout":"600"}
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] INFO  [24607] : Command processor should execute command.
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] DEBUG [24607] : Storing current stage..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] DEBUG [24607] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] DEBUG [24607] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.874Z] DEBUG [24607] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.875Z] DEBUG [24607] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.876Z] INFO  [24607] : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.878Z] INFO  [24607] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.878Z] DEBUG [24607] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.878Z] INFO  [24607] : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] DEBUG [24607] : Setting environment variables..
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] DEBUG [24607] : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.879Z] INFO  [24607] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.880Z] DEBUG [24607] : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2016-05-21T14:20:46.880Z] INFO  [24607] : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Below is my requirements.txt file.

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
blinker==1.4
cookies==2.2.1
Django==1.9.1
docutils==0.12
easygui==0.97.4
feedgenerator==1.8
Jinja2==2.8
Markdown==2.6.6
MarkupSafe==0.23
nose==1.3.7
pelican==3.6.3
Pillow==3.2.0
Pygments==2.1.3
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-forecastio==1.3.4
pytz==2015.7
requests==2.10.0
responses==0.5.1
selenium==2.53.2
six==1.10.0
Unidecode==0.4.19
urlparse3==1.0.8
virtualenv==13.1.2
```

Any clues on what's going wrong?

Comment: While I don't know exactly how to fix your problem, I would recommend trying to containerize your app, and then deploying it to beanstalk. That way you could perform your entire deployment process before uploading the app to beanstalk, and avoid these kind of errors. We have done this with our node app and it gave us a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Can it be that you have saved the file with a different encoding than UTF-8 or if it is some funny character that has made its way in there?

Comment: One or more of the requirements cannot be installed. Your log file is not complete so I cannot say which one. I know this might be late, but In Beanstalk, you can request the last 100 logs which in that it will specify exactly which requirement failed. you can paste it here and I'll be glad to help further.